# Outlook 2010 - VBA - Set bcc in ItemSend

Tags: vba, outlook, bcc

**Program:**    Outlook 2010
**OS:**         Win8
**VBA Skill:**  Novice

**Notes:**
This works perfectly if I remove the following option

```
Private Sub Application Item_Send  
'[3]
If Item.SendUsingAccount = "Account Name here" Then
```

If I do not remove it (keeping my BCC exception) the email on startup `Private Sub Application _Startup` runs *however* it BCCs *only* the email listed in item `[3]` = "special@domain.com".

When part `[3]` is removed both run as coded.
  1)  1 email on startup, BCCing all accounts listed to check the Macro,
  2)  During the day all emails sent have the correct BCC attached, all the exceptions work as coded.

It seems that there is something that I have missed which stops *every mail* code from running in to the *startup mail* code.

I have tried a number of changes, including added `IF` & `else` functions.

Both are run in my *This Outlook Session*

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties on startup
'Testing email settings, checking Macros enabled

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.mailItem
Set olApp = Outlook.Application

'Create e-mail item
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMail
    .Subject = "Login Test" & " | " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD - HH:mm:ss")
    .Body = "Testing the BCC" & " | " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
    .To = "1.alerts@domain.com; device@domain.com"
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .Send
End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    'source:    http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=72
    'source:    http://www.outlookforums.com/threads/89987-auto-bcc-vba-macro-how-add-exceptions/  (exceptions)  [2]
    'source:    http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/how-to-automatically-bcc-in-outlook-2010/#comment-312919 (sendusing) [3]


    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim strBcc As String
    'On Error Resume Next

    '[2]
    If Item.Categories = "zBCC no" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Item.To = "personal@domain.com" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If InStr(1, Item.Body, "zebra") Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                If Item.To = "1@domain.com" Or Item.To = "2@domain.com" Then
                    strBcc = "3@domain.com"
                    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
                    objRecip.Type = olBCC
                    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
                        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                        "Do you want still to send the message?"
                        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                        "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
                        If res = vbNo Then
                            Cancel = True
                        End If
                    End If
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    '[3]
                    If Item.SendUsingAccount = "Account Name here" Then
                        strBcc = "special@domain.com"
                        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
                        objRecip.Type = olBCC
                        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
                            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                            "Do you want still to send the message?"
                            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                            "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
                            If res = vbNo Then
                                Cancel = True
                            End If
                        End If
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        ' #### USER OPTIONS ####
                        ' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable to a name in the address book
                        strBcc = "1@domain.com"
                        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
                        objRecip.Type = olBCC
                        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
                            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                            "Do you want still to send the message?"
                            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                            "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
                            If res = vbNo Then
                                Cancel = True
                            End If
                        End If

                        strBcc = "2@domain.com"
                        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
                        objRecip.Type = olBCC
                        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
                            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                            "Do you want still to send the message?"
                            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                            "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
                            If res = vbNo Then
                                Cancel = True
                            End If
                        End If

                        strBcc = "3@domain.com"
                        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
                        objRecip.Type = olBCC

                        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
                            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                            "Do you want still to send the message?"
                            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                            "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
                            If res = vbNo Then
                                Cancel = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set objRecip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You  have made your IF structure very complicated. You can reduce you first 3 If/endif but specifying some thing like this `If Item.Categories = "zBCC no" Then Exit Sub` in one line. same for others

Comment: Quick question. Why are you assigning new values to BCC everytime? Or do did you actually wanted to do something like `strBcc = strBcc & ";" & "2@domain.com"`

Comment: @PradeepKumar that question was coming up later ;)  how do I reduce the amount of code when I want the 4 email addresses only :)  I've been trying with `email; email` and variations but kept getting errors, I'll try it your way now.

Comment: @PradeepKumar, Re your `IF` ques, I have reduced them down.  I've cut & pasted different parts of the code, so I don't know how to streamline any of it.  Re the `strBcc = "1@mail.com"
strBcc = strBcc & ";" & "2@mail.com"`  I receive a cannot resolve error, when I receive the resolve msg box I get another error: The operation failed.  Regardless each time the BCC field fills correctly.

Comment: No. You have to check if `strbcc` already contains something or not and then append to it. For example `If strBcc = "" Then strBcc = "1@domain.com" Else strBcc = strBcc & ";" & "1@domain.com"`

Comment: I have to leave office in some time. I will look at your reply once I get back home.

Comment: @PradeepKumar thank you. I will run some more tests using your info, it's 5am here, i'll check back later today.  I hijacked my own question to go off on my "strBCC" tangent.  OOps!

Comment: @PradeepKumar I have tried a number of ways of working with the multiple BCC addresses and each end up with a resolve error, or Outlook just refuses to do it.  I've posted it in it's own question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21675739/2337102

Answer (score 0):

My possibly false impression is, at the time you wrote this, you did not know how to debug. This may have been helpful http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Here is a simplified untested version. I removed all the Else statements.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    'source:    http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=72
    'source:    http://www.outlookforums.com/threads/89987-auto-bcc-vba-macro-how-add-exceptions/  (exceptions)  [2]
    'source:    http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/how-to-automatically-bcc-in-outlook-2010/#comment-312919 (sendusing) [3]


    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim strBcc As String

    '[2]
    If Item.Categories = "zBCC no" Then Exit Sub
    If Item.To = "personal@domain.com" Then Exit Sub
    If InStr(1, Item.Body, "zebra") Then Exit Sub

    If Item.To = "1@domain.com" Or Item.To = "2@domain.com" Then

        strBcc = "3@domain.com"
        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
        objRecip.Type = olBCC

        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
              "Do you want still to send the message?"
            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
              "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
            If res = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If

        GoTo ExitRoutine

    End If

    '[3]
    If Item.SendUsingAccount = "Account Name here" Then

        strBcc = "special@domain.com"
        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
        objRecip.Type = olBCC

        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
              "Do you want still to send the message?"
            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
              "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
            If res = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If

        GoTo ExitRoutine

    End If


    ' #### USER OPTIONS ####
    ' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable to a name in the address book

    strBcc = "1@domain.com"
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC

    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
          "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
          "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
            GoTo ExitRoutine
        End If
    End If

    strBcc = "2@domain.com"
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC

    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
          "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
          "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
            GoTo ExitRoutine
        End If
    End If

    strBcc = "3@domain.com"
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC

    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
          "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
           "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set objRecip = Nothing

End Sub
```

When you debug you will note Item.SendUsingAccount is always blank.

You can try setting SendUsingAccount [Use the mail account you want in your mail macro](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm) but it is a little trickier than SentOnBehalfOfName (From). Note manually setting From will not update SentOnBehalfOfName.

You can see how it works with this.

```
Sub SetSentOnBehalf()

Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(0)

objMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "bingo@bongo.com"

objMsg.Display

MsgBox " SentOnBehalfOfName in the From: " & objMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName

Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```