# How to automatically run a macro on opening a draft in Outlook? (add a BCC)

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to **automatically** achieve this workflow:

- *when* user opens a message draft in Outlook (a [generated EML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587397/generate-e-mail-message-for-outlook-with-bcc-filled-in))
- *if* the subject matches a string (immutable, known beforehand, I can't change it; it's something like `xyžřy`, note the non-ASCII characters):
- *then* add an e-mail to BCC field (immutable, known beforehand, valid e-mail address; let's say it's `baz@example.com`)

I already know the last part - [how to add a BCC to a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365624/add-bcc-to-email-with-vba-in-outlook-2013), and I use InStr for matching:

```
Sub addbcc()
Dim objRecip As Recipient
Set oMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

With oMsg

     If InStr(1, oMsg.Subject, "xyžřy") > 0 Then

        Set objRecip = oMsg.Recipients.Add("baz@example.com")
        objRecip.Type = olBCC
        objRecip.Resolve

    End If

End With

Set oMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, the user still needs to remember to press a button to run this macro, which is not more convenient than typing the BCC manually. Is it possible to run the macro *automatically* when this e-mail is opened?

Comment: I'm aware that this looks like an XY Problem ("well add the BCC to the generated draft, duh"). Alas, it seems that loading BCC from a draft EML message (my end goal) is something Outlook cannot do, so I'm looking for ork-arounds. There are add-ins for this, but I'm briefly exploring other alternatives that don't involve complex third-party code for such a tiny issue; I'm okay with eventually using such an add-in if no other options are available; but in a largish deployment, this wouldn't be "just fork over 20 bucks, add an auto-BCC rule and be done with it" (else I wouldn't even bother).

Comment: Are any of the examples on this page helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865989.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to run the macro automatically when this e-mail is opened?

Work with *[NewInspector Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171301%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)* , Events occurs when new window is opened by user or through your code.

Example

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    If Inspector.currentItem.Class = olMail Then
        If Inspector.currentItem.Parent = "Drafts" Then ' Drafts Folder

            Debug.Print Inspector.currentItem.Subject ' Immediate Window
            ' Call Your Code
            ' Inspector.currentItem.BCC = "baz@example.com"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

*[CurrentItem Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211820%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*

Answer (score 1):

You could monitor the drafts folder with ItemAdd.  See the idea here for the inbox.  [How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook)

You could add the bcc in ItemSend.  [Outlook 2010 - VBA - Set bcc in ItemSend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628397/outlook-2010-vba-set-bcc-in-itemsend)